# rsync wants to copy files that already exist in the destination directory

Tags: rsync

I am trying the following command using rsync to copy only files that

- are new
- have a different size

```
rsync -niav --size-only   /home/me/source/Electronica  /media/externalDrive/dest/Electronica
```

However, this dry-run results in the following output:

```
>f+++++++++ Electronica/music/AlbumArt_{F0CB439F-A1FC-47DB-A698-C561191F3FDE}_Large.jpg
>f+++++++++ Electronica/music/AlbumArt_{F0CB439F-A1FC-47DB-A698-C561191F3FDE}_Small.jpg
>f+++++++++ Electronica/music/Folder.jpg
```

which I interpret to mean that those files are copied. But they have the same size! (The times and flags are different, though). Also the rsync refers to an external hard-drive (with a different format).

I also tried the following commands:

```
rsync -niav --size-only --ignore-times  /home/me/source  /media/else
rsync -niav --size-only --ignore-existing /home/me/source  /media/else
```

But still, these files are shown in the same way, meaning they would have copied. What else can I try?

And what is wrong with the main page description?

```
--size-only     skip files that match in size
```

Comment: `>f+++++++++` indicates that the file (`f`) is copied (`>`) because it does not exist (`+++++++++`) on the remote side. Are you sure you're comparing the right paths (your current parameters will copy the *content* of `source` *into* `else/source`)?

Comment: I have updated the question to make it clear, the the last bit of the path I give to rysnc is the first bit of the path that is written out. I am not sure that is correct, but I am sure there is NOr directory `/home/me/source/Electronica/Electronica`. I interpret it that the files exist on both sides at the correct location...

Comment: If you've only run dry-runs so far, `rsync` will not have created `/home/me/source/Electronica/Electronica`, but will already check your source against its contents (of which there aren't any, of course).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You've fallen into `rsync`'s classical "trailing slash trap":
If the source path does not end with a slash, `rsync` will copy the source *directory*. If you intend to copy the *contents* of the source directory, it needs to end with a slash.

Let's look at an example, assuming you want to copy a file at `/home/me/source/Electronica/music/Folder.jpg`:

```
rsync -a /home/me/source/Electronica  /media/externalDrive/dest/Electronica
```

will copy the `Electronica` *directory* from the source to the destination, so it will create `/media/externalDrive/dest/Electronica/Electronica/music/` and put `Folder.jpg` in there.

```
rsync -a /home/me/source/Electronica/  /media/externalDrive/dest/Electronica
```

will copy the *contents* of the `Electronica` directory, so it will replicate the `music` directory under `/media/externalDrive/dest/Electronica/` (if it doesn't exists) and `Folder.jpg` will end up at `/media/externalDrive/dest/Electronica/music/Folder.jpg`.

---

To make matters more confusing, it does *not* matter if the *destination* path ends with a slash.

Just make a habit of ending all `rsync` paths with a slash, then you'll be safe from any nasty surprises.

Comment: Yes, I JUST realized. Happens to me all the time...